# Format-Table not taking effect (Exchange - powershell)

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

*first of all sorry if my english is not the best. but ill try to explain my issue with as much detail as i can*

Im having an issue where i cant get `Format-Table` to effect the output i give it.

below is the part im having issues with atm.

```
cls

$TotalSize = $($mailboxes. @{name = ”TotalItemSize (GB)”; expression = { [math]::Round((($_.TotalItemSize.Value.ToString()).Split(“(“)[1].Split(” “)[0].Replace(“,”, ””) / 1GB), 2) } });
$UserN = $($mailboxes.DisplayName)
$itemCount = $($mailboxes.ItemCount)
$LastLogonTime = $($mailboxes.ItemCount)

$allMailboxinfo = @(
    #lager dataen som skal inn i et objekt
    @{Username= $UserN; ItemCount = $itemCount; LastLogonTime = $($mailboxes.ItemCount); Size = $TotalSize}) | % { New-Object object | Add-Member -NotePropertyMembers $_ -PassThru }

$Table = $allMailboxinfo  | Format-Table | Out-String

$Table
```

the output of this gives me what almost looks like json syntax below each title of the table.

```
Username                                                                LastLogonTime                   ItemCount                       Size                           
--------                                                                -------------                   ---------                       ----                           
{username1, username2,username3,userna...} {$null, $null, $null, $null...} {$null, $null, $null, $null...} {$null, $null, $null, $null...}
```

running the commands by themselves seem to work tho. like `$mailboxes.DisplayName`  gives the exact data i want for displayname. even in table-format.

the reason im making the table this way instead of just using `select-object`, is because im going to merge a few tables later. using the logic from the script below.

```
cls

$someData = @(
    @{Name = "Bill"; email = "email@domain.com"; phone = "12345678"; id = "043546" }) | % { New-Object object | Add-Member -NotePropertyMembers $_ -PassThru }

$moreData = @(
    @{Name = "Bill"; company = "company 04"}) | % { New-Object object | Add-Member -NotePropertyMembers $_ -PassThru }

$Merge = @(
    #plots the data into a new table
    @{Name = $($someData.Name); e_mail = $($someData.email); phone = $($someData.phone); id = $($someData.id); merged = $($moreData.company) }) | % { New-Object object | Add-Member -NotePropertyMembers $_ -PassThru }


       #formatting table
$Table = $Merge | Format-Table | Out-String

#print table
$Table
```

if you are wondering what im doing with this.
My goal, all in all. is a table with using the info from Exchange;

DisplayName, TotalItemSize(GB), ItemCount, LastLogonTime, E-mail adress, archive + Maxquoata, Quoata for mailbox.

Answer (score 0):

You're creating a single object where each property holds an array of property values from the original array of mailbox objects.

Instead, create 1 new object *per mailbox*:

```
# construct output objects with Select-Object
$allMailBoxInfo = $mailboxes |Select @{Name='Username';Expression='DisplayName'},ItemCount,@{Name='LastLogonTime';Expression='ItemCount'},@{Name='Size';Expression={[math]::Round((($_.TotalItemSize.Value.ToString()).Split("(")[1].Split(" ")[0].Replace(",", "") / 1GB), 2) }}

# format table
$Table = $allMailBoxInfo | Format-Table | Out-String

# print table
$Table
```

Comment: oh, i might not have been to clear in my description. but im not using any of the data from the "merge" script. im only using the logic later to add sections from other tables. like i wrote at the very bottom of my question.

Comment: @walter My answer does not conflict with your plan to merge the data with other data sets. You can keep adding "columns" by piping to another `...| Select-Object` statement later if you need

Comment: ok, ill give it a go, thanks!

Comment: @walter You may want to ensure that you also select some distinct identifying property from the original mailbox (like the email address or user principal name) - this'll make it easier to correlate with other data sets later